# Javascript using a function to submit a form and print data below

Tags: javascript, html

I have been having trouble with the submit button while making this form, for some reason the method (in javascript) won't update the  with the form information at the bottom of the page when I press submit. I don't know if is something to do with a typo in the page or a logical error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> <title></title>


<script>

function update(){
     var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
     var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "First Name" + form.elements["name"].value
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id = "myForm">
First Name: <input name = "first" /><br />
Last Name: <input name = "second"/><br />
Date <input type="date" name = "date"/><br />
 Eye Colour <select name ="colour">
     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="green">Green</option>
     <option value="brown">Brown</option>
     <option value="grey">Grey</option>
     <optioin value = "other"> Other</optioin>
</select> <br />


<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button><br />
<button type="submit" onCLick = "update();" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<div id="status"></div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your submit button. It should be `onclick`, not `onCLick`.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="update()" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

As I keep looking, I notice more errors. You need to spend more time checking your own code, because some of these should be obvious. For example:

```
<optioin value = "other"> Other</optioin>
```

It should clearly be an `option` tag, not `optioin`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for semantics, it should be `onClick = "update();` not `onCLick = "update();` (capital L in onClick) but your problem is that you do not have an input with a name of "name", so

```
status.innerHTML = "First Name" + form.elements["name"].value
```

throws a null exception.

It should be:

```
status.innerHTML = "First Name " + form.elements["first"].value;
```

Hope it helps.